# How to apply mixamo mocap data to my character properly?

Tags: mesh, rigging, workflow, external-applications

I made a character for an academic project, which most of the pieces are floating. The next step was to upload this model to mixamo and test it with some pre-recorded animations, but I am having problems with the auto-rigging feature available in mixamo.

[image]

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Apply Rotation before import to Mixamo ....?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Has i sayed, im quite new to blender and mixamo, to be honest, to 3D also. Can you specify what i should do? Im gona edit the mixamo image, i sended the one that doesn't have the error message.

Comment: To apply rotation, press ctrl+a and click on rotation.

Comment: Sorry for short ... I was just thinking (@Relevred thanks) than start tested with simple model similar to yours https://imgur.com/pqt9t2X because I wasn't sure it can be split into separate objects and I ended with the same error, but Mixamo's puppet is also from two objects, than I thought if problem is distance ... some algorithms follows loops in topology, that doesn't seems to be the case ... for curiosity downloaded Mixamo puppet and exported from blender to obj failed but for different reason ... FBX worked ... conclusion - I don't know yet :) BTW what format do you use?

Comment: i used FBX to upload it to mixamo.
i also noticed that some object such as the arms are diferent in terms os distance compared to one another, im gona try to Shift+S and move them to the cursor and then use exact mesurements to put the pieces in place. I also tried to join all the pieces to make a single object, but still didn't work.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. I noticed that mixamo also lets you upload riged objects.. My question: to rig my golem do i have to join all the object? into a single one?

Comment: No, you can parent object directly to bone. Select object then with Shift select armature, switch to Pose mode, select a bone and Ctrl+P "Set Parent to Bone".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like Mixamo has a problem with distances. When I tried something similar to your model (just more primitive - Cones) it fails as well.

[image]

But adding spheres in place of connections worked. So the only one explanation for now I have - Mixamo doesn't know how to follow topology of your mesh. Tested with FBX Export / Limit to Selected.

[image]

[image]

You can delete or hide them later in Blender.

[image]

Comment: So basicaly conection the floating part, right? OK i will try it, thanks for the help! =D 
I will let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: Yes, objects or parts has to overlap. Later I tried just move a tip of cones into next one with just one sphere for hip to overlap legs with body cone and it worked as well. Documentation to Mixamo is very pour (Adobe bought something and doesn't care ...).

Comment: ya i also noticed that, they should specify more the couse of the errors. thanks for the help